# Getting cookies without doGet/doPost

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am making a dynamic web project with Java EE. If I understood properly, JSP pages are prepared in the server. So, if I want to read a cookie, I suppose that I don't need to do a get/post request to the server to read it.

And that's my question; how can I retrieve all the cookies that this user has without a formal doGet/doPost?

Answer (score 3):

If you use JSTL you can do something similar to that:

```
  <c:forEach items="${cookie}" var="currentCookie">
     ${currentCookie.name} - ${currentCookie.value}<br/>
  </c:forEach>
```

and outside of the `forEach` use `${cookie.cookieName.value}`

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, showing how one can get the list of cookies in a servlet with request.getCookie():

```
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

  @Override
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    req.getCookies();
    for (Cookie c : req.getCookies())
    {
      System.err.println(c.getName() + ":" + c.getValue());
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the following in a JSP:

```
<%

Cookies[] coockies = request.getCookies(); 

%>
```

This will return an array of cookies received in request.